# How to read the Result header XML tag in PL/SQL

Tags: xml, plsql

Soap Response:

```
s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
  <GetResponse xmlns="http://temp.org/">
     <GetResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ST" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:ResultHeader xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CRM">
           <b:ResultCode>0000</b:ResultCode>
           <b:ResultDescription>Successful</b:ResultDescription>

           <b:TranscationID>?</b:TranscationID>
        </a:ResultHeader>
```

Please suggest me how to read the resultcode and result description in response xml through pl/SQL, based on the Result code if result code is 000 then I will read the other child node values, else code is other then 000 then it will show the exception to user.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong tool for the job, it should be better to it application-side with an xml parser

Answer (score 0):

If in your XML will be only one `ResultHeader` node then you can check `ResultCode` by this way:

```
   -- get ResultCode value     
   l_resultCode:=  l_xml.extract('/s:Envelope/s:Body/GetResponse/GetResult/a:ResultHeader/b:ResultCode/text()', 'xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CRM" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CRM"').GetStringVal(); 

   -- check ResultCode
   IF l_resultCode = '000' THEN
       -- if OK then get value from child nodes  
   ELSE
       -- else raise exception
       l_resultDescription:= l_xml.extract('/s:Envelope/s:Body/GetResponse/GetResult/a:ResultHeader/b:ResultDescription/text()', 'xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CRM" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CRM"').GetStringVal(); 
       raise_application_error(-20001, 'ResultCode='||l_resultCode||', ResultDescription='||l_resultDescription);
   END IF;
```